# Function not returning properly when set to a variable but is when console.logged

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

The problem is in this function:

```
  function minimax(newBoard,player, depth = 0) {
    const availableSpots = emptySquares();
    // console.log(availableSpots)
    // console.log((checkGameStatus(newBoard,player) ? 'true' : 'false'))
    let score = {};
    
    if (checkGameStatus(newBoard, computerSymbol)) {
        console.log("Are we hitting here? 1")
        // console.log((onCheckWin(newBoard) === false))
        // console.log(newBoard,"o")
         score = { "score": (-100 + depth)}
         return score
    } else if (checkGameStatus(newBoard, playerSymbol)) {
        console.log("Are we hitting here? 2")
        // console.log(checkGameStatus(newBoard))
        // console.log(newBoard,"o")
        score =  { "score": (100 - depth)}
        return score
    } else if (availableSpots.length === 0) {
        console.log("Are we hitting here? 3")
        score = { "score": 0 }
        return score
    } 
    let moves = [];
    
    for (let i=0; i<availableSpots.length; i++) {
        let move = {};
      move.index = newBoard[availableSpots[i]];
      newBoard[availableSpots[i]] = player; 
      console.table(newBoard)
    if (player === computerSymbol) {
        let result = minimax(newBoard, playerSymbol , depth++);
        console.log(newBoard,"first");
        console.log(result)
        move.score = result["score"];
    } else {
        let result = minimax(newBoard, computerSymbol, (depth + 1));
        console.log(newBoard,"first");
        move.score = result.score;
        
    }
      console.log(moves,move)
      newBoard[availableSpots[i]] = move.index;
      moves.push(move);
      console.log(moves,move)
    } // end of for look
    
    let bestMove;
    
    
        if (player === computerSymbol) {
            let bestScore = -10000;
            for (let i=0; i<moves.length; i++) {
                if (moves[i].score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = moves[i].score;
                    bestMove = i;
                    // console.log(bestMove)
                }
                // end of for loop
            }
            if (player === playerSymbol) {
                let bestScore = 10000;
                for (let i=0; i<moves.length; i++) {
                    if (moves[i].score < bestScore) {
                        bestScore = moves[i].score;
                        bestMove = i;
                        // console.log(bestMove)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        } 
        
        return moves[bestMove];
    }
```

When I console.log the function inside of it, it returns an object, but when I set that function call to "result" like here:

```
 if (player === computerSymbol) {
        let result = minimax(newBoard, playerSymbol , depth++);
        console.log(newBoard,"first");
        console.log(result)
        move.score = result["score"];
```

I get undefined as the result and that I can't access property of undefined. Also, I seem to have a problem with my minimax algorithm where it's just constantly choosing the next open square. This might be because I am only using an empty board at the moment. I can add more code if need be, but it seems to me that the problem exists inside the function and not from one of my external or helper functions

Comment: Can you edit the question to include well-defined inputs and output? Show a concrete example of each.

Comment: This could use a [mcve].